# getting multidimensional array (object) observable in KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am building an application with Knockout and find it very useful.
Although, I have a problem with getting multidimensional array (object) observable.

At the moment I am using following structure:

```
    self.form = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(initialData, function(section) {
        var result = { 
            name : section.name, 
            code : section.code, 
            type : section.type, 
            fields: ko.observableArray(section.fields) 
        };
        return result;
    }));
```

It works well, but I can't get it working if the **initialData** is more than two levels.
I tried something like

```
    self.form = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(initialData, function(block) {
        var result = { 
            name : block.name, 
            code : block.code, 
            type : block.type, 
            sections: ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(block.sections, function(section) {
                var result = { 
                    name : section.name, 
                    code : section.code, 
                    type : section.type, 
                    fields: ko.observableArray(section.fields) 
                };
                return result;
            }))
        };
        return result;
    }));
```

The final array structure looks good, but knockout doesn't updates DOM when I am doing push to sections array:

```
    self.addField = function( section ) {
        field = {
            code: uid(),
            name: "New Field",
            value: '',
            type: section.type
        };
        section.fields.push(field); 
    };
```

I also tried a knockout.mapping.js plugin (is that a right approach?) looks good first, but after a push in the function above I have my new field element not observable, just object.

The plugin doumentation says:

```
// Every time data is received from the server:
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModel);
```

But I am not sure that it is my case.

If anyone has any ideas, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

UPD:
It is not a problem to make 1st and 2nd levels observable, problem is to go deeper.

Here is an example of **initialData**:

```
var blocks = [
    {
        "name" : "",
        "sections" : [
            {
                "name" : "Section 1",
                "fields" : [
                    {
                        "name" : "Field A",
                        "type" : "checkbox",
                        "code" : uid()
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

HTML

```
<div data-bind='template: { name: tpl-form-field-checkbox, foreach: fields }'></div>
<button class="btn addField" data-bind="click: $root.addField">Add</button>

<script type="text/html" id="tpl-form-field-checkbox">
    <input type="text" name="" value="<%= name %>" /> <br/>
</script>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see an example for initialData, if possible.

Comment: Also, can you post an extract of your HTML data bindings?

Comment: If you want your new field name to be observable you will have to use ko.observable('New Field') to make it observable.  Just adding an object to an observableArray doesn't make that object (or its properties) observable.

Comment: Thanks John, I got it now. I am using maping plugin and I realized that I need to ignore some properties of JS object (to not map them).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mapping plugin is the best way to go.  It will automatically map your objects into observables and observableArrays, so you don't have to do it manually.

Here is a simple fiddle that may give you some pointers: http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/CGh9b/

In this example I create a tree structure and them allow you to add a new entry.  You can see that I am able to continue to add at increasingly deeper levels with no problem, and because the names are observable they can be changed.