# knockout mapping of 3 dropdown lists using a JSON object containing 3 IList<CustomType>

Tags: json, knockout.js

Using Knockout I am trying to bind 3 dropdownlists with the data returned by an Ajax method calling a WebAPI.

The JSON data received is of Type "ReconDefMasters" where the calsses are defined as follows

```
public class MasterItem
{
    public int MasterItemID { get; set; }
    public string MasterItemName { get; set; }
}


public class ReconDefMasters
    {
        public IList<MasterItem> servFileFormat { get; set; }
        public IList<MasterItem> mersRev { get; set; }
        public IList<MasterItem> mersFileType { get; set; }
}
```

How to write the ko.mapping for this ?

I am able to achieve the result by returning IList, but then it requires 3 separate calls to the WebAPI- and trying to avoid this multiple calls by returning  a composite object of 3 ILists.

I referred the below links , but not successful in modifying the logic for 3 dropdownlist together

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/CGh9b/

[Poblem with getting multidimensional array (object) observable in KnockoutJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773756/poblem-with-getting-multidimensional-array-object-observable-in-knockoutjs)

This is my code for single IList<> Method

```
var apipath = 'http://example.com';

ko.validation.init({
    registerExtenders: true,
    messagesOnModified: true,
    insertMessages: false
});

function Master(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.FormatId = ko.observable(data.MasterItemID);
    self.FormatName = ko.observable(data.MasterItemName);
}

var RuleDefVM = function (url) {
    var self = this;

    self.ServFileFormat = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedTemplate = ko.observable();


    self.RuleDef = function () {

        jQuery.support.cors = true;

        $.ajax({ 
            type: "GET", 
            url: url, 
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            dataType: "json", 
            success: function (response) { 
                if (response != "") { 
                    $(response).each(function (index, element) {
                        self.ServFileFormat.push(new Master(element));

                    }); 

                } 
            } 
        });        
    };
}
var urlRuleDef = apipath + '/api/RuleDef/';
var viewModelRuleDef = new RuleDefVM(urlRuleDef);
viewModelRuleDef.RuleDef();
```

Comment: Are you asking how to serialise your `ReconDefMasters` object to JSON, or how to deal with that JSON on the client, or both?

Comment: How to deal with that JSON on the client - To Knockout bind  it to 3 dropdownlists

Comment: Your model needs to have 3 `observableArrays`, one for each `List` - you can then bind them individually in your templates etc

Comment: Feel free to add an answer with your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function Master(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.FormatId = ko.observable(data.MasterItemID);
    self.FormatName = ko.observable(data.MasterItemName);
}


    selfDef.ServFileFormat = ko.observableArray();
    selfDef.MERSRev = ko.observableArray();
    selfDef.MERSFileType = ko.observableArray();


    self.selectedTemplate1 = ko.observable();
    self.selectedTemplate2 = ko.observable();
    self.selectedTemplate3 = ko.observable();


        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                if (response != "") {
                    $(response).each(function (index, element) {
                        $(element.servFileFormat).each(function (index,element) {
                            selfDef.ServFileFormat.push(new Master(element));
                        });
                        $(element.mersRev).each(function (index, element) {
                            selfDef.MERSRev.push(new Master(element));
                        });
                        $(element.mersFileType).each(function (index, element) {
                            selfDef.MERSFileType.push(new Master(element));
                        });

                    });

                }
            }

        });


<select data-bind="options: ServFileFormat, value:selectedTemplate1, optionsText: 'FormatName' "class="dropdown"></select>

 <select data-bind="options: MERSRev, value:selectedTemplate2, optionsText: 'FormatName' "class="dropdown"></select>
<select data-bind="options: MERSFileType, value:selectedTemplate3, optionsText: 'FormatName' "class="dropdown"></select>
```